# How to parse given string using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

Given String:

```
<180>May 19 17:54:27 ise121 CISE_Internal_Operations_Diagnostics 0000046406 2 0 2015-05-19 17:54:27.930 +05:30 0000290168 34126 WARN  System-Management: Remote syslog target is unavailable
```

My RegEx :

```
\\<(\\d+)\\>(\\w+[\\d\\s\\:]+\\S+\\s\\S+\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s([\\d\\:\\-\\.\\+\\s]{0,30})\\s+\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+\\:.*?\\,)(.*)
```

but this is not working so please help

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchMoreLogsFromSingleRegEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "<180>May 19 17:54:27 ise121 CISE_Internal_Operations_Diagnostics 0000046406 2 0 2015-05-19 17:54:27.930 +05:30 0000290168 34126 WARN  System-Management: Remote syslog target is unavailable";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile("\\<(\\d+)\\>(\\w+[\\d\\s\\:]+\\S+\\s\\S+\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s([\\d\\:\\-\\.\\+\\s]{0,30})\\s+\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+\\:.*?\\,)(.*)");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("true");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int cnt = matcher.groupCount();
            System.out.println(cnt);
            for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; ++i) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i) + "\t" + i);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Please add some infromations, because you don't said what you would like to extract from this String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails to work because there isn't a comma exists  after the substring `System Management:` . So remove the last comma.

```
\\<(\\d+)\\>(\\w+[\\d\\s\\:]+\\S+\\s\\S+\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s([\\d\\:\\-\\.\\+\\s]{0,30})\\s+\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+\\:.*?)(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR4zQ1/3)

I think you want something like this. Here I made the comma part as optional.

```
\<(\d+)\>(\w+[\d\s\:]+\S+\s\S+\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s([\d\:\-\.\+\s]{0,30})\s+\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+\:(?:.*?,)?)(.*)
```

Escape the backslash one more time in java.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR4zQ1/4)